# A volatility score not sensitive to the overall scale of the variable

Tags: volatility

I want to measure volatility in my customer base using the last 5 years of activity. That is, a total of purchases summed by year over a 5 year period.

I plan to use this formula to calculate the variance (i.e. find the mean of the square deviations).

I'm wondering if this is the right calculation to answer the question - which customers are most volatile year to year. I mostly see volatility mentioned in relation to securities/stocks but this is a different use case. Is this the right approach or is there a better one?

EDIT: I'm not sure this is the right formula. Consider these examples:

- **record 1:** 2020, 2020, 2080, 2020, 2020
- **record 2:** 4, 8, 26, 50, 13

I think Record 1 is pretty consistent so it should have a low variance, but the variance is 576. Record 2 has high variability but a lower variance than record 1 (277). We have very big customers and very small customers and I want to show a variance irrespective of size. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Perhaps try the [coefficient of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation)?

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm going to use. Thank you for pointing it out. If you add this as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try the [coefficient of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation)? It is the ratio of the standard deviation to the mean and yields the relative variability/volatility (relative to the mean).